# how to add messages files recursively in build.scala of Play2.0 framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have messages file for each language in path: `release/linux/mhome/user/config/languages/sv/messages.sv`

I also have to mention path of each messages file in `Build.scala` as below:

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <+= baseDirectory(_ /  ".." / ".." / ".." / "release" / "linux" / "mhome" / "user" / "config" / "languages" / "zh" ),
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <+= baseDirectory(_ /  ".." / ".." / ".." / "release" / "linux" / "mhome" / "user" / "config" / "languages" / "en" ),
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <+= baseDirectory(_ /  ".." / ".." / ".." / "release" / "linux" / "mhome" / "user" / "config" / "languages" / "fr" ),
```

But I need to add path till languages folder in `Build.scala` and all the messages files get added recursively in classpath. How to achieve this?

Comment: You want to automatically add each found language in some path, or am I misinterpreting the question?

Comment: @johanandren I need to give path of parent folder and I am expecting that each messages files get added in classpath of play. With my approach I have to give absolute path of each messages file which is cumbersome way to add messages files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of the puzzle is to use <++= to add multiple entries to a setting key that is a list in one go

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <++= baseDirectory { dir => 
  ... something that returns a Seq[File] ...
}
```

The second part is the sbt PathFinder (http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Detailed-Topics/Paths.html), which allows you to specify wildcard patterns to find files:

```
val pathFinder = (".." / "shortened" / "for"/ "brevity" / "languages") ** "*"
val matching: Seq[File] = pathFinder.get
```

The PathFinder API also allows you to do more advanced filtering if you would need it.

Comment: As i am not at all aware of scala programming , kindly tell me if below code is fine to add in build.scala :                             unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <++= baseDirectory { dir => 
  val pathFinder = (".." / "magichome" / "xruser" / "config" / "languages") ** "messages.*"
  val matching: Seq[File] = pathFinder.get 
 },

Comment: Yeah, I think that should work. I really recommend that you spend some time reading the SBT-docs http://www.scala-sbt.org (which are very good) if you are going to do this kind of more-advanced-than-basic stuff. In addition to the sbt docs there is a good introductory MEAP "SBT in Action".

Comment: If I am putting the above code in build.scala of Play2.0 its giving me error as : Build.scala:21: value / is not a member of java.lang.String [error]val pathFinder = (".." / "mhome" / "xuser" / "config" / "languages") ** "messages.*"                                I just need to implement this in Play , for that i have to understand all concepts of scala.. :( :(

Comment: You need to have a file as your first path part or else it isnt a path, so it should start with (dir / ".."

Comment: what is the value of "dir" .If I am appending "dir" as below :unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <++= baseDirectory { dir => 
  val pathFinder = (dir /".." / "mhome" / "xuser" / "config" / "languages") ** "messages.*"
  val matching: Seq[File] = pathFinder.get 
 }, Still error is coming as :Build.scala:21: No implicit for Append.Values[Seq[java.io.File], Unit] found,[error]   so Unit cannot be appended to Seq[java.io.File][error]       unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <++= baseDirectory { dir
=>

Comment: baseDir() (or actually baseDir.apply()) which is what you are calling takes a function that will be called with the value of baseDir, so you are creating a function (File) => Seq[File] dir is the parameter name that you are giving that File parameter.

Comment: You are catching the matching seq of files in a val instead of returning it. Let the last line be just pathFinder.get (Scala returns the result of the last expression in the block) and it will work.

Comment: Thanks alot...it worked like magic..Now build.scala is getting compiled and I have put 1 println(pathFinder) also to see the exact path and path is also coming properly but now translation/internationalization of text is not happening.what could be the issue?

Comment: Are these file are getting added into classpath of Play?How can i assure this?

Comment: Load them through the class loader and you will know.

Comment: I printed the runtime classpath of play project but messages files are not getting included . Can you please suggest me some way how to add in classpath of play project